# Div with max-height: 200px; overflow: auto; Possible ?

Tags: html, css

Having a Div to show vertical list of images in `Scroll-able div`.

```
 <div id="sd" align="center"  style=" max-height: 200px; overflow: auto; " >

      <li><img src="1.jpg" .....
      <li><img src="1.jpg" .....
      <li><img src="1.jpg" .....
      <li><img src="1.jpg" .....
      <li><img src="1.jpg" .....
      <li><img src="1.jpg" .....

      ...
      ...


 </div>
```

I want that this div auto adjust its height as we change the height of Browser or open it on different screen sizes without loosing scroll bars  ,  `max-height: 100%;` not working here

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please add more infomation? Otherwise, does `<div id="sd" style="max-height: 200px; overflow: auto; text-align: center; height: 100%">` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **jQuery** for setting max-height property. For example try this:

```
$("#sd").height($(window).height());
```

or:

```
$("#sd").css("max-height", $(window).height())
```

also you can do any arithmetical operation:

```
$("#sd").height($(window).height() / 2);
$("#sd").css("max-height", $(window).height() / 3)
```

etc.